# How do I remove lines of a file which contain a specific string?

Tags: text-processing

How do I remove lines of a file (hosts) which contain  "adf.ly" string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### using `sed`

Run this command:

```
sed -i '/adf\.ly/d' inputfile
```

`man sed`

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
      edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

#### Using grep

Thanks for @kos notes:

```
grep -v "ad\.fly" inputFile  > outputfile
```

Comment: You're doing two different things in the `sed` and in the `grep` version: in the `sed` version you're deleting all the lines containing an `ad.fly` substring while in the `grep` version you're deleting only lines containing an `ad.fly` substring *surrounded by a non-word character* (i.e. *not surrounded* by `[A-Za-z0-9_]`); in the `grep` command also the `.` matches any character (i.e. it will exclude lines containing e.g. `adxfly`) and you're not using any of the `ERE`s' syntax in the pattern, so the `-E` option is not really needed.

Comment: However I didn't downvote this, drop me a comment if you ever correct this and I'll upvote it since the `sed` version is fine

Comment: @kos Even you downvote it's legitimated :). I removed the `grep` for now

Comment: Didn't saw your comment, anyway why did you remove the `grep` version? Just fix it, it can be useful

Comment: I will fix it before adding it again

Comment: Ok, upvoted the `sed` version then

Comment: No, the point is the `-w` option forces `grep` to match only `ad.fly` substring not surrounded by an alphanumerical or `_` character, so you should drop it if you want to make the `grep` version act the same as your `sed` version, which doesn't cater for that (and I guess that's the way it should act, since it looks like OP is trying to skip lines containing links). Also the pattern is wrong, the `.` in particular means "any character", i.e. lines containing strings such as `adxfly`, `adyfly` and so on will be matched. Just use the same pattern used in the `sed` version: `grep -v "ad\.fly"`

Comment: It works with `w` but I dont take care of `_` and other special characters, though i fixed it again. thanks

Comment: You could use `grep -Fv adf.ly input.txt > output.txt` for better performance on very large files.

Comment: +1 for `grep`, which is IMO the most straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The following will remove the lines containing "adf.ly" in `filename.txt` in-place:

```
sed -i '/adf\.ly/d' filename.txt
```

Use the above command without `-i` to test it before removing lines.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` (thanks to terdon for the shortened version):

```
< inputfile awk '!/adf\.ly/' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `awk`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `awk`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

`awk` command breakdown:

- `!/adf\.ly/`: prints the record if not matching the `adf\.ly` regex

---

Using Perl  (thanks to terdon for the shortened version):

```
< inputfile perl -ne '/adf\.ly/||print' > outputfile
```

- `-n`: places a `while (<>) {[...]}` loop around the script
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl command breakdown:

- `/`: starts the pattern
- `adf\.ly`: matches an `adf\.ly` string
- `/`stops the pattern
- `||`: executes the following command only if the pattern didn't match the line
- `print`: prints the line

Comment: Why not just `awk '!/ad\.fly/' in > out`? You could also shorten the Perl to `perl -ne '/ad\.fly/||print' file` if you're into golfing :)

Comment: @terdon Because I'm silly (`awk`) and anyway not that proficient in both languages. Thanks for your suggestions (by the way I didn't get the golfing reference!)

Comment: [Code golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) is the game of making code as concise as possible, usually at the price of sacrificing legibility. My point is that the perl alternative I gave is indeed shorter but yours was much clearer and more understandable to a non-expert.

Comment: @terdon Ah I see, yes I'd say I am then. After all it's sill explained right after

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `bash` one-liner:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r i; do [[ ! $i =~ .*adf\.ly.* ]] && echo "$i"; done <file.txt
```

- Variable `i` will contain each line while iterating
- [[ `$i =~ .*adf\.ly.* ]]` checks if the line has the string `adf.ly`, `!` negates the check so `[[ ! $i =~ .*adf\.ly.* ]]` will check if the line does not contain `adf.ly`
- If yes (`&&`), then the line will be printed.

To save the output to another file (`out.txt`):

```bsh
while IFS= read -r i; do [[ ! $i =~ .*adf\.ly.* ]] && echo "$i"; done <file.txt >out.txt
```

Comment: +1, just a little suggestion, you can directly pattern match against `adf\.ly`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the standard text editor, [`ed`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/adf\.ly/d' w q | ed file.txt
```

Comment: Great, a +1 for `ed` =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/adf\.ly/d' -cx hosts
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close